# MATLAB: How to compute the similarity of two signals and get the correct consistency or coherence metric

Tags: matlab, correlation, similarity

I was wondering about the consistency metric. Generally, it allows us to deduce the parity or similarity between two signals, right? If so, if the probability is higher (from 0.5 to 1), does it means that there is a strong similarity of the signals? If the margin is less than (0.1-0.43), can this predict the poor coherence between the signals (or poor similarity, the probability the signals are different)? So, if we got the metric <0, is this approved the signal is totally different? Because I'm getting negative numbers. Is this hypothesis possible?

Can I have a clear understanding of the consistency metric of the signal? Here is my small code and figure. Thanks in advance.

```
s1 = signal3
s2 = signal4     

if  s1 ~= s2
    [C1] = xcorr(s1);        
    [C2] = xcorr(s2);
    signal_mix = C1.*C2   %mixing vector
    signal_mix1 = signal_mix
else
    s1(1,:) == s2(1,:)
    s3 = s1
    s3= s2
    signal_mix = s2
end

n =2;
   
for i = length(signal_mix1)
    signal_mix1(i) = min(C1(i),C2(i))/ max(C1(i),C2(i)) % consistency score
    signal_mix2 = sum(signal_mix1(i))
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you could use `xcorr`function to calculate cross-correlation between two signals.
from Matlab [help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xcorr.html):

> r = xcorr(x,y) returns the cross-correlation of two discrete-time
> sequences. Cross-correlation measures the similarity between a vector
> x and shifted (lagged) copies of a vector y as a function of the lag.
> If x and y have different lengths, the function appends zeros to the
> end of the shorter vector so it has the same length as the other.

additionally you could use [xcov](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xcov.html):

> xcov computes the mean of its inputs, subtracts the mean, and then
> calls xcorr.
>
> The result of xcov can be interpreted as an estimate of the covariance
> between two random sequences or as the deterministic covariance
> between two deterministic signals.

in case of your example you are using xcorr with one signal so it computes auto-correlation between the signal itself and its lagged signal.

**update**:
based on the comment, it seems you need linear correlation, it can be calculated by corr function:

```
p=corr(x,y)
```

the value of p is 1 when x , y behave exactly like each other, and is -1 when x and y behave quite the opposite of each other.
when p is 0 it means there is no correlation between two signals.

Comment: Thanks, Mr @Hadi. I really appreciate your answer. I also think using the covariance and call xcorr should be the best way to solve the similarity. So, if the xcorr<0, implies that the signals are negatively related right? And if is -1 as a score, what does this mean? And one more question, if I'm getting a metric or score higher or superior to 0, is this approve the positive similarity of the signals? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case you might want to consider a **d**ynamic **t**ime **w**raping distance ([Matlab has a build in function for that](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dtw.html)) as similarity metric. One problem with using correlation as a metric is that it compares always the same timestep of the signals. So two identical signals, where one is time delayed, could lead to low correlation. The DTW distance adresses this by comparing to values of adjacent timesteps.

The downside of the dtw distance is that the distance it self can't be interpretet on its only only relative to other distances. So you can tell that two signals A & B with a distance of 150 are more similar than A & C with a distance of 250. But the distance of 150 on its own doesn't tell you a lot.

Comment: Thanks, Sir @Erysol. After applying the DTW, I'm getting a distance of 450 between both signals. What does this mean? they are any relationship between the signals or are completely different? Thanks in advance

Comment: As I tried to expain if you only do one companison the DTW distance doesn't tell you a lot. The signals would be identical if the distance is 0. Whether 450 is a lot you can only say if you did other comparisons. This can be useful if you have a reference signal and want to compare several to it and find which is the closest to it. This can also be used as loss-function for timeseries forecasting in machine learning.